# Column exist in mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have around 60 tables and some tables have column field name `uid`.I have a query that give details about database and table information schema.I just want to know check that in how many tables that `uid` column exist.Here is a query

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='records' AND column_name='uid'
```

Here it checks for one table.How could it  check for all tables?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME,(CASE WHEN C.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END) Result 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
        LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME 
AND C.COLUMN_NAME='uid'
```

It will list all your tables with result column

Comment: i want just  two columns first name of a table and second column for Exist that have value YES or NO

Comment: How did this work? it will produce a lot of duplicates records and he is selecting from the table twice! @WasiqMuhammad

Comment: And this will give both 'YES' and 'NO' for tables that has 'uid' column

Comment: *table twice!* - No , I just joined the COLUMNS with TABLES (left join ON COLUMN_NAME='uid'). So if the TABLE have column 'uid', then only the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS will show, otherwise it will show the NULL values, bcs it if left join. And all the conditions are in ON clause, Not in the WHERE clause. Please execute the query and check the result.

Comment: Table twice - No, but two tables - Yes. I didn't see you've selected once from columns and once from tables.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `TABLE_NAME` column from the where to the select:

```
SELECT t.table_name,
       max(CASE WHEN t.Column_name = 'uid' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as YourInd
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t
GROUP BY t.table_name
```

Comment: i want just two columns first name of a table and second column for Exist that have value YES or NO –

Comment: Unknown column 't.TABLE_NAME' in 'field list'

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad I fixed the solution to one with only one select from the table instead of two

Answer (score 0):

To fit your requirement: *"I just want to know check that in how many tables that uid column exist"*:

```
SELECT count(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE column_name = 'uid'
```

To fit your second requirement: *"i want just two columns first name of a table and second column for Exist that have value YES or NO"*

```
SELECT t.table_name, if(c.column_name = 'Ref', 'yes', 'no') as exist 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS c
left join information_schema.tables t
on t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
group by c.TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: i need two columns first colum **table name** second column **exist** that have enum like YES or NO

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it.

`SELECT TABLE_NAME, CASE WHEN column_name = 'uid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'EXISTS' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS GROUP BY TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Use following query.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
   CASE
       WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'uid' THEN "YES"
       ELSE "NO"
   END AS 'EXISTS'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='<database_name>'
  AND COLUMN_NAME='uid'
```